# ID from Controller#show

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I would like to retrieve the id of the current item in a Controller#show page. How is this done? I can't seem to figure this out or find it anywhere.

Comment: It would help if you said why you want to do this. Your question is quite brief!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably looking for:

```
<%= params[:id] %>
```

There are lots of things wrong with doing this, one of which is it can open you up to CSRF attacks. Make sure to escape your output (this is done automatically in rails 3.)